# Envelope theorem applied to Optimization

Tags: calculus, optimization

[image]

I differentiated the maxim with repect to $r_1$ to get (c), however that is incorrect, according to the solutions (a) is the answer. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first order necessary condition states that:

$$r_1 x^{r_1-1} - r_2 = 0$$

from which:

$$ x^* = \frac{r_2}{r_1}^{ \frac{1}{r_1-1} } $$

Plugging it back in $f$:

$$ f \left( x^* \right) = \left( \frac{r_2}{r_1}^{ \frac{1}{r_1-1} } \right)^{r_1} - r_2 \left( \frac{r_2}{r_1}^{ \frac{1}{r_1-1} } \right) $$

Then you just simplify it and differentiate w.r.t. $r_1$ in accordance with the Envelope Theorem.

Comment: Thanks, managed to figure out last night I hadn't plugged in the FOC. Thanks for taking the time, much appreciated.